# Powershell - Appending to array overriding all values

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to append an object to an array of objects however when adding it is overriding all values

Script:

```
foreach ($i in $users.Users){
    
    if($i.UserName -like "JS*"){
        
        $object.Username = $i.UserName
        $object.name = $i.name
        $array += $object
        $array
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Username                                              Name
--------                                              -----------
JSmith                                                John Smith
JSmith                                                John Smith
JSmith                                                John Smith
```

Expected:

```
Username                                              Name
--------                                              -----------
JSmith                                                John Smith
JStone                                                John Stone
JTimber                                               Juliette Timber
```

Interestingly enough if we have a look at each loop the table output looks like:

Iteration 1:

```
Username                                              Name
--------                                              -----------
JSmith                                                John Smith
```

Iteration 2:

```
Username                                              Name
--------                                              -----------
JStone                                                John Stone
JStone                                                John Stone
```

Iteration 3:

```
Username                                              Name
--------                                              -----------
JTimber                                               Juliette Timber
JTimber                                               Juliette Timber
JTimber                                               Juliette Timber
```

Comment: What is `$object` in your code? Reason why this happens is because you're updating the same reference (the same object) instead of creating a new one. `$array = $users.Users | Where-Object UserName -Like JS* | Select-Object UserName, Name` most likely solves your problem.

Comment: As an aside: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficiënt.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell puts a reference to the object in the array, not the value of the object directly. So when you update the object, then anything that references it will also be updated. E.g. test this out:

```
$array = @()
$object = [PSCustomObject]@{username = $null}
$array+=$object

$array
username
-----
#blank

$object.username = "one"

$array
username
-----
one
```

If you want to get around that, you can define a new object in your loop:

```
$object = [PSCustomObject]@{username = $i.UserName;name=$i.name}
```

Fully updated you could do this:

```
$array += $users.Users | where UserName -like "JS*" | % { [PSCustomObject]@{ username = $_.UserName ; name=$_.name} }
```